# How capture "Enter" in shell?

Tags: shell

The following script can capture the 4 arrow keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    read -n 3 c  
    case "$c" in
      $'\033[A')
        printf "\t up \n"
        ;;        
      $'\033[B')      
        printf "\t down \n"
        ;;
      $'\033[D')     
        printf "\t left \n"
        ;;
      $'\033[C')    
        printf "\t right \n"
        ;;
      *)   
        if [[ $c == "" ]]
        then
            printf "\t enter \n"
        fi
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done
```

I obtained the sequences of characters of arrow keys from [Input Translation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Input-Translation.html) and [n](https://github.com/tj/n)。

In the script, <kbd>Enter</kbd> is captured by a different way. Can <kbd>Enter</kbd> be captured by a similar way with arrow keys ?

### supplement

The following code can **not** work correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    read -n 1 c  
    case "$c" in
      $'\n')
        printf "\t enter \n"
        ;;        
      *)
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done
```

I have found a right way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while true; do
    read -n 3 c  
    case "$c" in
      "")
        printf "\t enter \n"
        ;;        
      *)
        exit
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: To capture enter in your switch statement , use the empty-string `""` in your case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment above, in your `case` statement, you will want to test for the `empty-string` represented by double-quotes `""`. That will match someone inputting nothing and just pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Here is a short example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r ans

case "$ans" in 

    ""  )
        printf "[Enter] - empty string found\n";;
    *   ) 
        printf "missed enter.\n";;
esac

exit 0
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ bash readrtn.sh

[Enter] - empty string found

$ bash readrtn.sh
anything
missed enter.
```